# How to validate entries in Tkinter for unique value every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to know how can we validate Tkinter Entry to put unique value everytime we insert something in the entry box. I have been asked this in a project where we have to input rollnumbers but we have enter unique one every time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: uh how can we do this -_-)'

Comment: Tell us more about how you are storing the student's record

Comment: Uh i sent you a Github of my project before but i will tell you that i am storing data in JSON file.

Comment: Are you searching by Id?

Comment: I don't get it.. searching? I get the values from entries and store it in JSON file and I just want to put unique values every time my teacher said that we can validate but didn't explain how. Please can you tell me the way to validation.

Comment: If the user has to enter unique values each time then your program must check whether the value already exists in your file. I'll share how to check whether the value exists in the dict. Is that fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind 'Enter' key or any other key of your choice to the `Entry` so when the user presses enter, an event handler is called which then checks if the data is already present in the file. To get the text from `Entry` use the `get` method eg:`Entry.get()`.
Then check whether the item alerady exists.(Note: There must be a unique column from which you can identify each row of the table which in your case is 'roll_no')

So, here is a demonstration from your previous code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


titles={'Id': [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 'Names':['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim'], 'Column': [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}

def search(event=None):

    if not entry.get().isdigit():
        return
    
    if int(entry.get()) in titles['Id']:
        lbl.config(text='Already exists', fg='red')

    else:
        lbl.config(text='Doesn\'t exists', fg='green')

root = Tk()


treev = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode ='browse') 
treev.pack(side='left',expand=True, fill='both') 
  

verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root,  
                           orient ="vertical",  
                           command = treev.yview) 
  
verscrlbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='y')   
treev.configure(yscrollcommand = verscrlbar.set) 

treev["columns"] = list(x for x in range(len(list(titles.keys()))))
treev['show'] = 'headings'

  
for x, y in enumerate(titles.keys()):
    treev.column(x, minwidth=20, stretch=True,  anchor='c')
    treev.heading(x, text=y)

for args in zip(*list(titles.values())):
    treev.insert("", 'end', values =args) 

lbl = Label(root, text='', fg='Red')
lbl.pack()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.bind('<Return>', search)
entry.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='Search', command=search)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

(The above code gives feedback to the user telling whether the value already exists).